Set up Flamenco to support multiple Blender versions?
I have some older workstations that are not supported by the latest versions of Blender, but I still use interactively. I want to send jobs from these workstations to my Flamenco/Blender "farm" (garden, flowerpot?), and have them rendered with the same (older) version of Blender.
I can handle the installations of multiple Blender versions in the farm, but am trying to figure out the best way to have multiple job types (or a switch for the existing job type) to specify which version of Blender to use.
Has anyone already done this?

This is what tags are for. In short:

Go to the 'Tags' tab in the Manager's web interface.
Create a tag "Older Only".
Go to the 'Workers' tab.
For each older Worker, click on it, then click the slider next to the "Older Only" tag to assign that worker to that tag.
When submitting a job, choose either "All" or the tag "Older Only".

The tag used when submitting a job will determine which workers get to work on it. Of course it's up to you which tags you choose, and which workers you assign. Maybe you find it easier to have a tag specifically for the newer computers.

so, I would need to do a 2nd worker install on my compute nodes, tag them, and hardwire their configuration to point to the older Blender? That'll work; but then there is a chance that a compute node could end up running 2 jobs.
I'll use it as my interim solution.
I think I'll put a feature request in. Having a single worker with the ability to run one of several Blenders makes sense. I might be able to pull it off with a custom job type.

You don't need 2 workers. You didn't specify that you'd want to run two different versions of Blender on the same machine (just "in the farm"), that requires a bit of a different setup.
Tags control which Worker gets to work on which job. If you want to have different versions of Blender for different jobs, that would require a custom job type. I can help with that too, but it's easier to go to Blender Chat at https://blender.chat/channel/flamenco for that.
